# Is it possible to use wildcard variable inside a child directory?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've been working on my security rules for my ionic app, I've been wondering if wildcards can be used as an additional directory for a child in a rule.

this is my rule which currently has denied access error

```
"rules": {
    "Download": {

      "$id": {  

        ".read":"root.child('password/'+$id).child('password').val() === 4321"

      }  
    }
}
```

while this is my rule using the complete child directory which is working

```
"rules": {
    "Download": {

      "$id": {  

        ".read":"root.child('password/12342').child('password').val() === 4321"

      }  
    }
}
```

this one, is the Download node

```
Download: {
   4123: {
      id: 01
    user:john
   }
   3123: {
      id: 01
    user:john
   }
}
```

Password node

```
password: {
   12342: {
     password: 4321
     id: 01
   }
}
```

this one is the receiving function,

```
    let qwee = await new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       return firebaseRef.child('QuizDownload/3123')
          .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
              //console.log(snapshot.val());

              //data.push(snapshot.val());
             // data
             console.log(snapshot.val());
             //resolve(data);


              //container.push(snapshot.val());

           }, function(err) {
             console.log(err);
             reject(err);
           })
        }); 


  }
```

Can you advise what should be the error using wildcards as additional to the directory?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The `root.child('password/'+$id)` should expand to a path `/password/$id` with `$id` being the name of the node that triggered the rule. Is that not happening for you?  How are you testing?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, it seems I've got a little understanding about it, the wildcard that the 'Download' node has should be the same wildcard with the 'password' node

Comment: That's how your rules work already. If you'd read `/Download/3123`, it'd only allow the read if `/password/3123/password` is `4321`. Is that not working for you? That'd be surprising, but in that case you might want to try `root.child('password').child($id).child('password')...`.